# Deleted item still appearing on home page after deleting from database in MERN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, mern

I am creating a blog website using MERN stack and used context API for state management, in which I'm showing all the blogs on the home page but as soon as any blog gets deleted or added, the blog page redirects to the home page and deleted blog still appears and also newly created blogs doesn't appear there(because of fetching blogs from API before it gets deleted or added), any workaround other than reloading the home page?
Using fetchBlog() inside useEffect() on mounting of homepage component.

```
const { blogs, getAllBlogs, loading } = useContext(BlogContext);
useEffect(() => {
    getAllBlogs();
  }, []);
```

from https://github.com/gupta-piyush19/Blogic/blob/main/client/src/components/Pages/Home.js

and

```
const saveHandler = () => {
    if (title === "" || image === "") {
      setAlert("Please fill all the fields", "warning");
    } else {
      const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
      createBlog({
        title,
        image,
        body: JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(contentState)),
      });
      history.push({
        pathname: "/",
      });
    }
  };
```

from https://github.com/gupta-piyush19/Blogic/blob/main/client/src/components/Editor/DraftEditor.js
on creating a new blog, the website will redirect to the home page but the newly created blog may not be there.
If its not very clear then please try to create a new blog on this app and you will understand the problem.
https://blogic-app.herokuapp.com/

Comment: by now there is no way to answer you question due to lack of details. do you fetch actual posts after switching back to home page? if you don't - then why? if you do - then how exactly?

Comment: @skyboyer, yes I'm fetching posts on homepage, and the function to get all posts is running on mounting of homepage.

Comment: better add code samples to the question. sure, not complete components' sources but route config + fetching part of home page + code that navigates to homepage

Comment: @skyboyer I have updated the problem statement, can you please help me out ?

Comment: as far as I can see in DevTools, your code is correctly requests `GET /posts` right upon creation. But why this endpoint returns stale data without entry just created? I don't know, but it's definitely not React part's issue. You need to dig into server code, and update this question accordingly.

Comment: I am not able to find what the error actually is, but most probably it's because creating a new entry takes time and my app is fetching data in between the process.

Comment: you can try with making `createBlog` returning Promise and make `history.push` only when it's fullfiled